# Handling of Japanese with Jquery.serialize();

Tags: jquery, unicode, encoding, serialization, encodeuricomponent

Hoo boy. A weird one I guess!

getting input from a form, I want to make sure there are no western characters, punctuation or numbers before sending it to a php script for creating some xml...

from form name = "a"

```
$('form').submit(function() {

text = ($(this).serialize());

text = text.substr(2,text.length)

text = text.replace(/[^\u3040-\u30FF^\uFF00-\uFFEF^\u4E00-\u9FAF^\u3400-\u4DBF]/g,'');
```

---> text goes to php script using .ajax

However, the Japanese is being converted to ASCII before it gets to the regex!

eg. あああ　becomes %E3%81%82%E3%81%82%E3%81%82

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would swap it around and change the inputs before serializing, like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find(':text, textarea').val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[^\u3040-\u30FF^\uFF00-\uFFEF^\u4E00-\u9FAF^\u3400-\u4DBF]/g,'');
  });
  var text = ($(this).serialize());
  //submit form....
});
```

This uses [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get and replace the old value based on the regex before the serialization (and more importantly, [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent) gets called in there).

---

Another alternative is to do the regex yourself in the middle of the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) steps, like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var arr = $(this).serialzeArray();
  $.each(arr, function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\u3040-\u30FF^\uFF00-\uFFEF^\u4E00-\u9FAF^\u3400-\u4DBF]/g,'');
  });
  var postData = $.param(arr);
});
```

[`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is really just `$.param($(this).serializeArray())` so all we're doing is splitting it up here, taking the `value` of the `{name:'name',value:'value'}` object pairs in the array that [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) creates and running the regex on each.  After that we're passing the changed array, western-character-less to [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to get serialized as a string.